# Bootstrap class "form-inline" Break inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m trying to stop/break the `form-inline` class inside just one div.
I have three input fields.
I´d like the two first one left side, ontop of each other.
And the third on the rigth side of them.

check Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rjc5s1vn/

This is a pretty large form, so i don´t like to remove form-inline from the parent form.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline well col-md-10">
  <!-- Produkt input-->
  <div class="input-group col-md-4 form">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></div>
      <input id="produkt" name="produkt" type="text" placeholder="Produkt" class="form-control input-sm">
      <br>
      <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></i></div>
      <input id="objekt_lev_dat" name="objekt_lev_dat" type="text" placeholder="Leverans datum" class="form-control input-sm" required>
    </div>
    <!-- Adress Textarea -->
    <div class="input-group col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i></div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="objekt_mont_adress" name="objekt_mont_adress" rows="3" placeholder="Adress" required>    </textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:`<br>`

Notice more nestled `<div><br>`

```
<!-- Product input-->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 0px">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></div>
            <input id="produkt" name="produkt" type="text" placeholder="Produkt" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></i></div>
            <input id="objekt_lev_dat" name="objekt_lev_dat" type="text" placeholder="Leverans datum" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: https://jsfiddle.net/rjc5s1vn/3/

I wrapped your `inputs` and glyphicons pairings into two wrapping `<div class="test">`:

```
<form class="form-inline well col-md-10">
  <!-- Produkt input-->
  <div class="input-group col-md-4 form">
    <div class="test">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></div>
      <input id="produkt" name="produkt" type="text" placeholder="Produkt" class="form-control input-sm">
    </div>
  <br>
    <div class="test">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></i></div>
      <input id="objekt_lev_dat" name="objekt_lev_dat" type="text" placeholder="Leverans datum" class="form-control input-sm" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Adress Textarea -->
  <div class="input-group col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i></div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="objekt_mont_adress" name="objekt_mont_adress" rows="3" placeholder="Adress" required></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.form-inline > .input-group:first-child > .test {
  display: block;
}
.form-inline > .input-group:first-child > .test div, .form-inline > .input-group:first-child > .test input  {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I guess this will work. But i solved it with less code. Just like you i wrapped the inputs with more divs...

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. You can try by this way. I just used core bootstrap and some css. Have a look on my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/rjc5s1vn/8/)

```
<form class="form-inline well col-md-10">
<div class="item">
<div class="input-group input-group-sm input_item">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
</div>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm input_item">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">@</span>
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm input_item">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
</div>
<div class="clearfix">

</div>
</div>
</form>



.form-inline .item .input_item{
  width:calc(50% - 7.5px);
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.form-inline .item .input_item textarea{
  min-height:75px;
}
.form-inline .item .input_item:first-child{
  float:left;
}
.form-inline .item .input_item:nth-child(2){
  float:right;
}

.form-inline .item .input_item:last-child{
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try out this

```
    <form class="form-inline">

    <div class="input-group col-md-4 form">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></div>
    <input id="produkt" name="produkt" type="text" placeholder="Produkt" class="form-control input-sm">
    <br></div>

  <div class="input-group col-md-4 form">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></i></div>
    <input id="objekt_lev_dat" name="objekt_lev_dat" type="text" placeholder="Leverans datum" class="form-control input-sm" required>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i></div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="objekt_mont_adress" name="objekt_mont_adress" rows="3" placeholder="Adress" required></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rjc5s1vn/4/)

Comment: This is not what i wan´t at all. I can´t use the glyphicons with it..and i dont like the label..

Comment: Test the above example on larger screen